# Beamer: Can't use itemize within if-statement

Tags: beamer, conditionals, itemize

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \ifdim\textwidth=\textheight
            equal
        \else
            \begin{itemize}
                \item unequal
            \end{itemize}
        \fi
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Above code-snippet leads to a failed compilation with the following error:

```
! Incomplete \ifx; all text was ignored after line 11.
<inserted text> 
\fi 
<*> test.tex
         
The file ended while I was skipping conditional text.
This kind of error happens when you say `\if...' and forget
the matching `\fi'. I've inserted a `\fi'; this might work.

! Emergency stop.
<*> test.tex
         
*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)
```

However, when I use the same if-construction in a plain `scartcl` document or if I replace the itemize environment with some plain text, the compilation works just fine.

So it seems that beamer is somehow modifying the `itemize` environment which somehow interferes with my if-statement.

Does somebody know what exactly is going on here and how one might be able to work around this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Frames are very fragile and the error is at a rather low level.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}[fragile]
        \ifdim\textwidth=\textheight
            equal
        \else
            \begin{itemize}
                \item unequal
            \end{itemize}
        \fi
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you happen to be able to give just a rough explanation of why the error is produced in the first place and why `[fragile]` fixes it? I know that marking frames as fragile fixes all sorts of errors in beamer, but how does this relate to the `\fi` now being registered in this case?

Answer (score 3):

While I still don't know *why* the above MWE fails (I can only assume that beamer uses some if-wizardry in its modified version of `itemize` that interferes with the outer if-statement that I added to the code), I at least found a workaround making use of a macro defined in the `etoolbox` package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \ifdimcomp{\textwidth}{=}{\textheight}{%
            equal
        }{%
            \begin{itemize}
                \item unequal
            \end{itemize}
        }
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This seems to encapsulate the outer if-logic from what is going on in the different branches (sufficiently) in order to avoid the previously encountered error.